# Template and static files setup with Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I have some trouble getting my templates to work. Overall very unsure how to setup the static files and templates in my project directory.

Should I as best practice place my templates inside the app folder when under development and my static files inside the app folder as well?

**This is the output:**

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/projects/test/main/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tinymce/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mce_filebrowser/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/conf/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/core/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/generic/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/pages/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/blog/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/forms/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/galleries/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mezzanine/accounts/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/avatar/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/filebrowser_safe/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/grappelli_safe/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_comments/templates/main/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r"^$", "main.views.home", name="home"),
```

**views.py:**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "main/templates/index.html", context)
```

**settings.py:**

```
PROJECT_APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_APP = os.path.basename(PROJECT_APP_PATH)
PROJECT_ROOT = BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_APP_PATH)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            #os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                "mezzanine.conf.context_processors.settings",
                "mezzanine.pages.context_processors.page",
                "main.context_processors.global_settings",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

What could be the cause of this? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Where are the template files actually located?

Answer (score 2):

I'm just deducing this because you have not provided this information:

1. your app is called `main`
2. your template `index.html` is *really* located at:
   `/Users/username/Dev/test_dev_01/projects/test/main/templates/index.html`

If my presumptions are correct, your call to render should read:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```